# Create usable python function from a c string (sympy use case)

Tags: python, c, string, sympy, dynamically-generated

I have some c code which I generate on the fly from somewhere (in my case it's   sympy.printing.ccode) and it looks like this:

```
c_code = "1.17647058823529*(-1.0L/3.0L*pow(-pow(x, 2) + 1, 1.0L/3.0L) + 1)*exp(4.70588235294118*I*M_PI*x)/sqrt(-pow(x, 2) + 1)"
```

In python how do I define f(x) so I can do:

```
#TODO:  f = SOMETHING(c_code)

for x in numpy.linspace(.1, .9, 100)
    some_value = f(x)
    print some_value
```

I understand I can always eval() a string of python code inside a function. Is there some elegant way to "evalc()" a string of c-code inside a function?

(ps 1 - I know I can evalf(), or lambdify() from sympy directly and avoid this, but that is super slow, and really falls apart for multivariate functions which have to be evaluated on large domains)

(ps 2 - I know I COULD modify the string to BE the source for a compilable python module, THEN write the string to a file, THEN exec( 'command line c compile' ) on that file, and THEN import the c-module from python, and THEN run the function - but that seems like a silly long chain of fragile steps to just convert a string into run-able c, especially if I can trust the source because it came from a package I like )

Comment: ps 2 seems like the most logical choice to me if you're doing C work, C is met to be compiled into binary, anything other than that is inherently going to be troublesome. Otherwise I'd say you switch to a language that was met to be interpreted on the fly, such as lua, lisp, erlang, javascript, or even python.

Comment: If it is any help for option 2, I wrote [two](//github.com/neurophysik/jitcdde) [modules](//github.com/neurophysik/jitcode) that do this under the hood. So it’s clearly possible and there is some code for you to reuse..

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ahaaaa! - so I am not alone. The desire to work in python, and numerically evaluate in C isn't crazy. It seems like the `jitcode` package has the ability to do option 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lambdify`, or if you want a fast function (compiled into C), use `ufuncify`.  `ufuncify` requires a compiler.

Example:

```
f = lambdify(x, sqrt(x), 'numpy')
```

or

```
f = ufuncify(x, sqrt(x))
```

Also, with either case, for performance, you should evaluate the function on the array directly, like `f(numpy.linspace(.1, .9, 100))`. Avoid looping over NumPy arrays manually; that will kill your performance.

Comment: Great answer for sympy specific compiling